# Fails to parse Hebrew text from pdf using iText 7 with .net

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, itext7

I am trying to read a PDF file with several pages, using iText 7 on a .NET CORE 2.1
The following is my code:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1100, 1100);
LocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
inputStr = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDocument.GetPage(i), strategy);
```

inputStr gets the following string:

```
"\u0011\v\u000e\u0012\u0011\v\f)(*).=*%'\f*).5?5.5*.\a \u0011\u0002\u001b\u0001!\u0016\u0012\u001a!\u0001\u0015\u001a \u0014\n\u0015\u0017\u0001(\u001b)\u0001)\u0016\u001c*\u0012\u0001\u001d\u001a \u0016* \u0015\u0001\u0017\u0016\u001b\u001a(\n,\u0002>&\u00...
```

and in the Text Visualizer, it looks like that:

```
)(*).=*%'*).5?5.5*. !! 
())* * (
,>&2*06) 2.-=9 )=&,

2..*0.5<.?
.110
)<1,3
    2.3*1>?)10/6
     (& >(*,1=0>>*1?

    2.63)&*,..*0.5

   206)&13'?*9*<
    *-5=0>
  ?*&..,?)..*0.5
```

it looks like I am unable to resolve the encoding or there is a specific, custom encoding at the PDF level I cannot read/parse.

Looking at the Document Properties, under Fonts it says the following:
[image: PDF Document Properties Fonts Settings]

Any ideas how can I parse the document correctly?

Thank you
Yaniv

Comment: Hi, can you post the PDF for analysis? Might be an issue in the file or might be a bug in library

Comment: For a first guess, what do you get copying&pasting from your pdf in Adobe Reader?

Comment: @AlexeySubach I can't post the PDF as it includes sensitive data. I’ll try masking the sensitive data and post.

Comment: @mkl Copying&pasting works perfect

Comment: In that case the pdf is required for further analysis.

Comment: @mkl thanks for the help. Can I share it offline somehow? I don't it to be public... appreciate your help

Comment: You can find an email address in my stack overflow profile. But sending it only there obviously means only I can analyze it, not others like @Alexey who works for itext. And most likely I won't be at a PC before tomorrow to start analyzing...

Comment: @mkl appreciate your help. I sent the document.

Comment: @AlexeySubach - can I send it over to you as well offline? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Analysis of the shared files

### file1_copyPasteWorks.pdf

The font definitions here have an invalid **ToUnicode** entry:

```
/ToUnicode/Identity-H
```

The **ToUnicode** value is specified as

> A stream containing a CMap file that maps character codes to Unicode values

*(ISO 32000-2, Table 119 — Entries in a Type 0 font dictionary)*

**Identity-H** is a *name*, not a *stream*.

Nonetheless, Adobe Reader interprets this name, and for apparently any name starting with **Identity-** assumes the text encoding for the font to be UCS-2 (essentially UTF-16). As this indeed is the case for the character codes used in the document, copy&paste works, even if for the wrong reasons. (Without this **ToUnicode** value, Adobe Reader also returns nonsense.)

iText 7, on the other hand, for mapping to Unicode first follows the **Encoding** value with unexpected results.

Thus, in this case Adobe Reader arrives at a better result by interpreting meaning into an invalid piece of data (and without that also returns nonsense).

### file2_copyPasteFails.pdf

The font definitions here have valid but incomplete **ToUnicode** maps which only contain entries for the used Western European characters but not for Hebrew ones. They don't have **Encoding** entries.

Both Adobe Reader and iText 7 here trust the **ToUnicode** map and, therefore, cannot map the Hebrew glyphs.

## How to parse

### file1_copyPasteWorks.pdf

In case of this file the "problem" is that iText 7 applies the **Encoding** map. Thus, for decoding the text one can temporarily replace the **Encoding** map with an identity map:

```c#
for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
{
    PdfPage page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
    PdfDictionary fontResources = page.GetResources().GetResource(PdfName.Font);
    foreach (PdfObject font in fontResources.Values(true))
    {
        if (font is PdfDictionary fontDict)
            fontDict.Put(PdfName.Encoding, PdfName.IdentityH);
    }

    string output = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page);
    // ... process output ...
}
```

This code shows the Hebrew characters for your file 1.

### file2_copyPasteFails.pdf

Here I don't have a quick  work-around. You may want to analyze multiple PDFs of that kind. If they all encode the Hebrew characters the same way, you can create your own **ToUnicode** map from that and inject it into the fonts like above.

Comment: by the way, when you read the file, were you able to read it RTL? all input appears LTR for me...

Comment: It is LTR. The string `output` has to be post-processed accordingly, maximal sub-sections with characters from RTL scripts have to be inverted, or (if in a foremost RTL context) the whole string has to be inverted and then maximal sub-sections with characters from LTR scripts therein have to be inverted again.